# Retrieve Table output from sql server stored procedure in to PHP variable

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've a sql server stored procedure that returns a table in php and format it in php. Here is the relevant part of the code that deals with that

```
$tsql_dropSP = "IF OBJECT_ID('spGetPivot', 'P') IS NOT NULL
              DROP PROCEDURE spGetPivot";

$stmt1= sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql_dropSP);

if( $stmt1 === false )  
{
 echo "Error in executing statement 1.\n";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


$tsql_createSP = "create Proc spGetPivot (
                            @CHR AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
                        )

AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @query1 NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @queryO NVARCHAR(MAX) 



SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + ChrLocus + ']', '[' + ChrLocus +       ']')
FROM    
(SELECT DISTINCT Chromosome+'_'+ CAST(Locus AS VARCHAR(10))ChrLocus 
    FROM ProgenyRawJuly14 
    where Chromosome in ('Gm11')
    --,'Gm11', 'Gm12', 'Gm13', 'Gm14', 'Gm15', 'Gm16', 'Gm17', 'Gm18', 'Gm19', 'Gm20')
)PV 

ORDER BY ChrLocus



SET @query1 = 'SELECT Strain_ID, COLNAMES as Markers, ' + @cols + '
into #temp
FROM 
(  -- Source data for pivoting
SELECT CONCAT(Chromosome,''_'',Locus) ChrLocus,Strain_ID,Markers, COLNAMES, sort
FROM ProgenyRawJuly14   
CROSS APPLY(VALUES (1, MarkerSet1,''MarkerSet1''),(2, MarkerSet2,''MarkerSet2''),(3, Parent1_Marker,''Parent1_Marker''),(4, Parent2_MarkerA,''Parent2_MarkerA''),
(5, Parent2_MarkerB,''Parent2_MarkerB''))
AS COLUMNNAMES(Sort, Markers,COLNAMES)
UNION 
SELECT CONCAT(Chromosome,''_'',Locus) ChrLocus,Strain_ID,Markers, COLNAMES, sort 
FROM ParentRawTableJuly14 
CROSS APPLY(VALUES (1, MarkerSet1,''MarkerSet1''),(2, MarkerSet2,''MarkerSet2''),(3, Parent1_Marker,''Parent1_Marker''),(4, Parent2_MarkerA,''Parent2_MarkerA''),
(5, Parent2_MarkerB,''Parent2_MarkerB''))
AS COLUMNNAMES(Sort, Markers,COLNAMES)

) x

PIVOT 
(
   --Defines the values in each dynamic columns
 min(Markers)
 -- Get the names from the @cols variable to show as column
 FOR ChrLocus IN ('+ @cols +')
) p 
order by Strain_ID, sort;

SELECT @queryO=COUNT(*) FROM tempdb.sys.columns WHERE object_id =            object_id(''tempdb..#temp'');
SELECT * INTO temptable FROM #temp;'
select * from temptable;
END";

$stmt2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql_createSP);

if( $stmt2 === false )
{
 echo "Error in executing statement 2.\n";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$getProducts="";

$params = array(
array($chrom_set,SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
array($getProducts,SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT)
);

$tsql_callSP = "{call spGetPivot( ?,?)}";

$stmt3 = sqlsrv_query($conn,$tsql_callSP,$params);


 if ( $stmt3 === false) { echo "Error in executing statement 3.\n";
        die( FormatErrors( sqlsrv_errors() ) );}

 $productCount = 0;     

 echo $stmt3;
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in executing statement 3.
```

I tried several suggestions in the online forum: but none works. I'm new to this stored procedure part in sql server. Not sure whether I'm using the variables and output parameters correctly.

Comment: What is the code of the stored procedure when you try to execute it in statement 3?

Comment: @Tab: The stored procedure is in $tsql_createSP in the above code.It is created in statement 2.

Comment: Try executing the stored procedure call in SSMS and see if you get a more specific error message.

Comment: @Tab:  the query works fine in SSMS. The problem is in retrieving the query results to PHP variable..

Comment: Any possible solutions to fix this?

Comment: I don't know, the problem must be in PHP, and I am not a PHP expert.   But if the procedure works in SSMS, then the SQL must be fine.

Comment: @Tab- Yes it is in passing the output from SQL to PHP. I couldn't find good documentation for this one..Even the forums have only a few threads dealing with this. None of the solutions worked...

Comment: Hopefully a PHP expert will come along and offer a solution.

Comment: Hope so...Have also posted this in PHP freaks forum...Thanks Tab..